# Setting Logback Configuration file Programmatically

Tags: sbt, logback

I'm using the sbt run command to run my project. My project uses the Logback logging mechanism and if I would like to enable logging, then I have to use the following command:

```
sbt -Dlogback.configurationFile=/path/to/log/file/app-logger.xml run
```

Is there a way that I could set this programmatically? I mean I would like to just say

```
sbt run
```

and it picks up automagically the app-logger.xml by itself via the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I do it!

```
  def loadLogger() = Option(System.getProperty("logback.configurationFile")) match {
    case Some(logXml) =>
      logger.info(s"using logger $logXml")
    case None =>
      val path = s"${System.getProperty("user.dir")}/conf/app-logger.xml"
      System.setProperty("logback.configurationFile", path)
      logger.info(s"using logger $path")
  }
```